# How to access web api from another web app which is in same Azure AD?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have hosted a web api `ProductInfo` on Azure and register that application into Azure AD.

I have another web app `UIProduct` and this web app want to access the web api ProductInfo. Both are in same Domain and same Azure AD.

How can I access web api `ProductInfo` from web app `UIProduct`?
Is there any token I need to generate again?

Code sample taken from [this link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs).

After a successful login I'm at home page, then I click on about page where I write this.

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> About()
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("App ID URI", credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://demotest.azurewebsites.net/api/getdata");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Getting exception:

> Failed to acquire token silently as no token was
> found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Comment: I answered to the best of my ability, but I recommend cleaning up the formatting of your question and providing more info on the experience you're trying to build. It's a little bit unclear exactly what points have confused you, let me know if my answer is missing anything!

Comment: You want an ad app access another ad app?

Comment: yes! i tried this code sample but failed to generate token for webapi but unable to generate token
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to go register both apps in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) both as Web Apps/APIs.

Then in your Web API, set a `App ID URI` as well as create any scopes you'd like to expose. If this is the only client you'll be using, you may be able to just have an `Access` scope, but bear in mind this is what end users will see when consenting to your app.

In your web app, you'll then be able to set a `Required Permissions` for this new web API and scope. This indicates that the client should require consent for this web API and can be granted access tokens for it.

[This code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) covers this exact scenario.

The [web API basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api) doc also covers some conceptual info related to this scenario

Comment: great thanks a lot i got it , but issue i face is sample code is .net core , i'm using mvc web app and i do not find this code in my webapp mvc `User.FindFirst` which is inside `class ClaimsPrincipal` may i go with any nuget for claim for mvc ?

Comment: [.NET core MVC](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) here you are!

Comment: nope its `ASP.NET Core web application` i'm working on `ASP.NET MVC` few code is not there into `Asp.Net MVC from here`

Comment: This is for .Net Core , I want it for .Net MVC

Comment: Ah, my bad, thought you were looking for .NET core.  In the initial code sample I linked, I believe the Web App is an MVC app. [MVC component](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/master/TodoListWebApp). Apologize if I'm missing something nuanced, not a .NET expert :)

Comment: i have taken code from this link 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/
but still problem is same :(